# What is the maximum amount of time CPU can be in critical section after acquiring spinlock?

Tags: linux-kernel, locking, spinlock

What is the maximum amount of time CPU can be in critical section after acquiring
Spin lock in Linux kernel?

Comment: It could be as much as you want until you do `spin_unlock()`. It could even be a dead-lock if you do it the ugly way.
Another matter is "how to implement spin-locking properly"

Comment: Until it affects other code.

Comment: Will it also not depend on the time slice of that thread as well? AFAIK each process/thread has a time slice till it executes on a CPU. However, if it again gets its time slice, it might still be in critical section. So, I think, the processor can execute other tasks, but the thread acquiring spinlock can be in waiting state forever. Correct me if I am wrong.